# Allow region reps to have RO to global mship info - but only to their own regional records. Db field or tag for "region"?

Tags: wordpress, acl, tags

As the title says, I need to appoint reps for each region who can access their "own" regions records to send mailings. We are using Wordpress and everything is the latest versions.
Is "region" best as a DB field and/or a tag in this case?
Regional reps should have no access to membership records outside their own area.
Please be patient with me, I have just inherited an existing CivCRM system that seems as if it was set up in a hurry. I am just getting to grips with CivCRM - Please feel free to explain things very s l o w l y.

EDIT: Is this something I must bite the bullet on and accept that I can only get this functionality in Drupal?
I have a very little Drupal experience, but I am much more comfortable with WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Relationships and adding this extension which then means you can use the Relationships as the way of controlling who sees which records

https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion but I would look to setup regions as organisation sub types and then have relationships for all the contacts who belong to it. At the same time you'd have a relationship for the main contact i.e. the contact that is the regional rep. You would then build your views or alternatively give them access to CiviCRM using ACLs?